# Protocol driver not attached (hfs+)

Tags: drivers, partitioning, mount, hfs+

On a 12.04 LTS system, I am attempting to mount an SSD that was formerly in a Macbook Pro. It has four partitions, one with a Ubuntu install, one for swap, one a Macintosh recovery partition, and the fourth is a OS X install. Both Macintosh partitions are HFS+.

I have the drive in an external enclosure. When I plug it in, my machine auto-mounts all for partitions, but fails on "Macintosh HD" (the OS X install partition) saying, "protocol driver not attached." I am able to mount and explore the recovery partition just fine, as well as the Ubuntu and swap partitions.

When attempting to mount via:

```
~$ sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/sdb2 /media/external
```

I get the same results:

```
~$ mount: Protocol driver not attached
```